# К какому слову относится перечисление после двоеточия?

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие, смысл, деловой-язык

Фрагмент из Постановления правительства РФ от 29 октября 2002 года № 781 «О списках работ, профессий, должностей, специальностей и учреждений, с учётом которых досрочно назначается трудовая пенсия по старости в соответствии со статьёй 27 Федерального закона «О трудовых пенсиях в Российской Федерации», и об утверждении правил исчисления периодов работы, дающей право на досрочное назначение трудовой пенсии по старости, в соответствии со статьёй 27 Федерального закона «О трудовых пенсиях в Российской Федерации» (с изменениями и дополнениями):

Наименование учреждений
21 **Санатории (курорты), в том числе детские**:
для лечения туберкулёза всех форм;
для больных с последствиями полиомиелита;
для гематологических больных;
для лечения больных с нарушениями опорно-двигательного аппарата;
для больных ревматизмом;
психоневрологические.

Перечисление профилей санаториев относится ко всем санаториям или же только к детским? Или же здесь двоякий смысл?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нет двоякого смысла: указанные в списке профили санаториев (курортов) относятся ко всем возрастным категориям — и для взрослых, и для детей.

*Санатории (курорты), включая детские.*

Ефремова: [**в том числе**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/144717/%D0%92) — союз; употребляется при присоединении члена предложения, который является частью целого (*о котором говорится в первой части предложения*), соответствуя по значению словам: ***включая** кого-либо или что-либо, в том числе и.*

МАС: **в том числе** — среди других, в ряду других. *Среди отличившихся при овладении городом были дивизии и полки, пришедшие с Кавказа после боев на Тамани, в том числе и полк Воротынцева* (Павленко. В ночь под Новый год).

Comment: Нет, двоякий смысл, по грамматике может относиться и только к последнему.

Comment: Так не честно, если в столбик, то такая интерпретация уже не подходит.

Comment: У автора вопроса и было в столбик, только без двойного пробела (поэтому выстроилось в одну строку). Посмотрите — до правки. Я только исправила название Постановления и выделила обсуждаемый кусок.

Comment: Всё равно надо бы сказать, что в плане грамматики возможны оба варианта. А более логичный (в том числе исходя из оформления), конечно, этот.